# pandas dataframe: identifiy NaN and zero values in one statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to combine the two statements
`df.isnull().sum()` and
`(df == 0).sum()` to get the following overview?

Demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,0,1,3], 'b':[0,NaN,1,NaN,1], 'c':[0,0,0,0,NaN]})

df

    a   b       c
0   1   0.0     0.0
1   0   NaN     0.0
2   0   1.0     0.0
3   1   NaN     0.0
4   3   1.0     NaN
```

Expected result:

```
a    2
b    3
c    5
```

Probably very simple, but I can't find the solution... 
Thank's for your help

Comment: What's wrong with just `(df==0).sum() + df.isnull().sum()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean just this:

```
In[27]:

(df==0).sum() + df.isnull().sum()
Out[27]: 
a    2
b    3
c    5
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @coldpseed for the suggestion, you can also do the following:

```
In[28]:
df[df!=0].isnull().sum()

Out[28]: 
a    2
b    3
c    5
dtype: int64
```

which is more succinct, I've always been more in favour of clarity but shorter code sometimes wins.

Comment: `df[df != 0].isnull().sum()` to do it with one sum call... by the way, nice to see you around :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks, that seems neater, should I include? I took a long hiatus from SO after being a bit disillusioned and also very busy at work, just dipping my toe figuratively speaking back in

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it was meant for you to add it in! We need our old veterans back, there is no better time for your return.

Comment: ohh ... that's exactly what I was looking for. I suspected that a special expression exists for this query *lol* Thanks for your help!

Comment: @stomar02 it's best not to overthink things, here by using `+` the resulting series will align naturally on their indices so it's not as complicated as it seems

Answer (score 5):

With `fillna`

```
df.fillna(0).eq(0).sum()
Out[8]: 
a    2
b    3
c    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Another neat option here (fillna _may_ be slow on larger frames), but unless performance is key, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
>>> ((df == 0) | df.isnull()).sum()
a    2
b    3
c    5
dtype: int64
>>>
```

Also:

```
>>> (df.eq(0) | df.isnull()).sum()
a    2
b    3
c    5
dtype: int64
>>>
```